# Can I name an output file from an output node?

Tags: export, compositing-nodes, file-format

When I give a new name to a File Output, Blender ignores it.

It is using this name to create a new folder instead in which it is saving the image. Can I give a name to an output files or can they only be called Image0001?

[image]

Comment: I see you are using a complete destination path including a file base name and suffix (.png) in the Base Name.   Your probably causing some unpredictable result.   Remove the "3.png" from the Base Name.  blender will automatically add the .png based on your File Format selection.    Note how only pahs are showing in the example in https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Base Path* field is only used to specify a folder.
To modify the name, use the node's *File Subpath* in the Sidebar.

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't write directly to a "C:", "D:", "E:" drive base root directory in Blender. You need to create a folder. Blender is assuming 3.png is going to be your "root base" folder. This is something implicit Blender does. You can "D:\myFolder\3.png" and it will work. Also, consider changing the number from: "3.png" to "alpha3_.png" Always name your files describing them alphanumerically. Numbers in a sequence should contain "_" to separate the last character against the automatic sequence generated number from the timeline as a good practice.

Comment: I followed your advise, but the problem still remains. It is the same also when I add _ to the end of the name.

Comment: Hello :). Just tried it, and it seems blender actually *can write* directly to the base root directory under Windows.

Comment: Fantastic, Jachym. I tried it back in 2.83, this was not possible. I am glad someone addressed it.